# How to replicate all list, libraries and site pages to sub-site?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

Am creating a sub-site problematically and i want all list, libraries and site pages to replicate in sub-site. Can we do that?

I have below error shows up while doing Save site as template

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below can get you started.

You need to save your source site as template(where all list/libraries and site pages are created). 
To Save site as Template -
Go to site settings-

Navigate to the top-level site of your site collection.

Click Settings  SharePoint Online Public Website Settings button and then click Site Settings.

In the Site Actions section, click Save site as a template.

NOTE: The Save site as a template option may not be available in all situations. For more information, see the section Troubleshoot a custom site template below.

Specify a name to use for the template file in the File name box.

Specify a name and description for the template in the Template name and Template description boxes.

To include the content of the site in the site template, select the Include Content check box. The limit is 50 MB and cannot be changed.

IMPORTANT:  Before creating a site template that includes content, check the workflow history list for the site. If there are thousands of items in the list, it may take a long time to create the site template or you may exceed the limit of 50 MB. In this case, it’s a good idea to modify the workflow association to a use new workflow history list and then delete the original workflow history list before creating the site template.

Click OK to save the template.

If all of the components on the site are valid, the template is created, and you see a message that states "Operation Completed Successfully."

Do one of the following:

To return to your site, click OK.

To go directly to the site template, click Solutions Gallery.

** use this template while creating sub-site, and all the site structure will be stapled.** Below code I have not tried but it should be something similar.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://rootweb"))
        {

            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("Subsiste");

            SPWebTemplate SiteTemplate = null;

            foreach (SPWebTemplate wt in web.GetAvailableWebTemplates((uint)1053)) // 1053 is locale code (language of site), for EN-US use LCID 1033, Sweden 1053 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664
            {

                if (wt.Title == "Template_Name_123") 
                {
                    SiteTemplate = wt;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (SiteTemplate != null)
            {
                string SiteURL = "project_123";
                string SiteTitle = "Project 123 Site";
                string SiteDescription = "Site for Project 123!";
                SPWeb newWeb = web.Webs.Add(SiteURL, SiteTitle, SiteDescription, (uint)1053, SiteTemplate, false, false); // 1053 is locale code (language of site), for EN-US use LCID 1033, Sweden 1053 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664

                //the code that does something with created site goes here, "newWeb."! examples: (etc)
                //newWeb.Navigation.UseShared = true;
                //newWeb.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
            }

        } //using rootweb
```

Comment: When i hit OK i.e  while creating template, its throwing technical error. What may be the problem?

Comment: can you expand technical details and check with correlation id...there may be may reasons a template is not getting created...!!

Comment: Note that if it's a publishing site, saving it as a template will cause you many problems, so have this in mind as well. Otherwise, Siddarth solution should work just fine +1

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli Then what is the Correct way to do this?

Comment: Siddharth way is correct, if you don't have a publishing site. Do you have a publishing site?

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli : should i refer sub-site as template

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli : yes

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize the PnP team's way of doing this, by following the practices mentioned here:

https://dev.office.com/blogs/introduction-to-office-365-dev-pnp-provisioning-engine

As you have a publishing site, saving a site as a template won't be the way to go, although it would be fine and correct as Siddharth mentioned, but in case you have a publishing site, I strongly recommend following the guidelines of the PnP team with the provisioning engine which works for Office 365 as well.

Watch the video in the link provided, you'll understand the new way of doing this thing as site templates aren't recommended anymore by Microsoft.